# Moment on a body and on a simply supported beam

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment, structural-beam

[image]

Consider a body on a frictionless floor being acted upon by a force F as shown in figure. Force acts on its centre of mass. (Centre of mass and centre of gravity coincide in this case, ie, both lie on same point) CG marked in the figure.

**CASE 1**The object accelerates and does not show any rotation since the force acts on it CG. But if we consider a point P on the object as shown, there is a moment acting about the point P, yet it does not experience a torque in real life scenario. Physics seems promising.

**CASE 2** Also, consider the case of solving simply supported beams. We find that no moment is produced about any point on the beam.

My question is why the things considered on case 2 is not applicable in the case mentioned above.

To be precise, in one of the cases we consider moment about centre of mass only to explain whereas in another case we consider moment about all the points in the beam.

Comment: Can you attach an image of case 2?

Comment: Oops, missed that the floor is frictionless. Deleted my answer and will post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

***My question is why the things considered on case 2 is not applicable in the case mentioned above.***

***To be precise, in one of the cases we consider moment about centre of mass only to explain whereas in another case we consider moment about all the points in the beam.***

If I understand your question correctly, it is because there is no friction on the supporting surface of the block and therefore no horizontal force to oppose the applied horizontal force. Therefore, as long as the applied force is through the CG there will be no rotation.

The same does not apply to a simply supported beam. The pin support of the beam would oppose a horizontal force applied to the end of the beam where supported by the roller. See the diagrams below where the lower figure represents the block as a simply supported beam.

Note that if the horizontal force is greater than mg, it will cause rotation about the pin even if it is applied through the CG. For static equilibrium requirements to be met, the sum of the moments about any point of the beam must be zero.

To summarize, the difference between a simply supported beam and a beam on a frictionless surface is that horizontal motion of a simply supported beam is constrained by the pin.

ADDENDUM:

This will respond to your follow up comments.

***My question is why there is no rotation about point P. I am not talking about the horizontal forces on a simply supported beam...but the vertical forces on a simply supported beam***

The third diagram below shows a simply supported beam with an arbitrary downward vertical load F one-fourth the distance of the beam from the left. For the beam to be in equilibrium, the reaction forces at the supports must be as shown. I’m sure you agree that the sum of the moments about any point along the beam, including P, are zero and thus there is no rotation about P nor any other point along the beam.

***Having taken any point, the sum of the moments about the point equals zero in a simply supported beam where as in Case 1, there should be a rotation possibly happen since moment about the point P is non zero.***

So, you agree that the sum of the moments about P for a simply supported beam are zero and therefore there is no rotation of the beam about P.

For your Case 1, there can be no rotation about P simply because the supporting surface constrains rotation, if any, to occur at a corner. In order to rotate about P, the block would need to go below the surface. See the top diagram. Essentially, the reaction of the supporting surface to the left of P would prevent it from rotating about P. If the block were floating in space with nothing to oppose rotation, it would rotate about P.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: you quoted "If I understand your question correctly, it is because there is no friction on the supporting surface of the block and therefore no horizontal force to oppose the applied horizontal force. Therefore, as long as the applied force is through the CG there will be no rotation ".  My question is why there is no rotation about point P. I am not talking about the horizontal forces on a simply supported beam...but the vertical forces on a simply supported beam

Comment: Having taken any point, the sum of the moments about the point equals zero in a simply supported beam where as in Case 1, there should be a rotation possibly happen since moment about the point P is non zero.

Comment: @Vinayak See the ADDENDUM to my answer.